# What is natural logarithm of this expression?

Tags: logarithms

What is natural logarithm of this expression?

$y = 4*[x^9*x^6]$

Is it

$\ln(y) = 4 * [ 9\ln(x) + 6\ln(x)]$

or

$\ln(y) = \ln(4) + 9\ln(x) + 6\ln(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y=4[x^9*x^6]$ so you have $$y=4x^{9+6}=4x^{15}$$ and so $\ln(y)=\ln(4x^{15})$ and so $$\ln(y)=\ln(4)+15\ln(x),~~x> 0$$

Comment: If i have -4 instead of 4.. ln(-4) is not possible.. so it will become -ln(4)?

Comment: @Syeda: Look at the definition of natural log. It must not be happened or be assumed unless you have other conditions for $x$. It is forbidden for `ln`.

Comment: okay, thanks!! So can I assume it -ln(4) ? Because i have negative value..

Comment: @Syeda: I said `ln(-4x), x<0` is acceptable but if you wanna make them separate you'll walk on a ground full of mines. It 's dangerous.

Comment: okay!! I got it.. Thanks!!